# How can I display only the first screenfull of output, including all terminal colours, and lines that will be wrapped?

Tags: bash, terminal, pager

I have a command (a compiler) that can output lots to the terminal when there's a compilation problem. Some of the lines are longer than my terminal is wide, and it also uses terminal colours  (red text for errors etc). I want to run that command, and only show the first screen/page of output, but taking account of line wraps & colours.

**Update** I am using `cargo`, the Rust compiler, and if there's a syntax error, it will produce lots of output, including colours. with `--colors=always`, and `|&` I can show both. e.g. `cargo build --colors=always |& head -n 20` shows the first 20 lines. I want to show the first page only, so that I can

I use `entr` to auto run `find ./src/ -type f -name '*.rs' | entr -r bash -c 'cargo build -- color=always |& less -R` will not work, because the `less` command gobbles everything and I can't stop it. In fact that hides all output.

Comment: Have you tried piping your output to `less` with `-RS` and scrolling horizontally with your arrow keys? `yourcommand | less -RS`.

Comment: @Kahn I think less -R is the way to go, because OP wants to keep wraps, not remove them.

Comment: @Quasímodo yep - I wasn't really understanding that part. Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're just looking for `less -R`:

```
  -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like  -r,  but  only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in
          "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained cor‐
          rectly  in  most  cases.
```

That flag tells `less` to interpret ANSI color sequences, so the output should be just the same as on your terminal.

If all you want is to get the first N lines where N is the current size of your terminal window, use `$LINES`:

```
find ./src/ -type f -name '*.rs' | 
    entr -r bash -c 'cargo build -- color=always |& head -n $LINES
```

Or, since the prompt when you launch the command and the one printed after it finishes both take up one line:

```
find ./src/ -type f -name '*.rs' | 
    entr -r bash -c 'cargo build -- color=always |& head -n $((LINES-2))
```

Comment: That's part of the way there, but it lauches an interactive terminal programme, rather than stopping at the first page. I just want the output to be the first page.

Comment: @Rory OK, could you edit your question then and tell us what compiler you are using? Are the ANSI sequences kept if you redirect/pipe the output (many tools detect when they are being piped or redirected and remove the colors)? If they are kept, it's very easy, but if not it can get more complicated.

Comment: I'm using `cargo`, Rust's compiler. It has a `--color=always` flag, so I can ensure the colours are there

Comment: @Rory ah, good. So how do you define a page? How may lines?

Comment: “page” = “one screenful of my current terminal”

Comment: @Rory so you just want `cargo ... | head -n $LINES`? That will print the first page, the LINES variable is set to the height of the current terminal. Is that really all you need?

Comment: That was my initial attempt, but when long lines are wrapped it will show more than one screenful of text. e.g. if one line is wrapped, then my terminal (`gnome-terminal`) will show `$LINES + 1` lines of output, so the first line of output will be out of view

Comment: `less -RX +1Gq` shows the first screen and quits.